# Why are we allowed to multiply in a system of equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know how to solve it, but I am not quite sure on why it works, multiplying both sides of an equation in the form $ax + by = c$ should raise every $y$-value by that which you multiplied. The purpose of the system of equations is to find the coordinates in which they intersect, however by raising the $y$-values would the point where they intersect not change as well? The only point that would remain the same is $y=0$ because $o*any number$ is still $0$. So why are we allowed to multiply and then eliminate the system of equations to find a coordinate? This is related to highschool math btw.

Comment: The solution to the equation $x=1$ is $x=1$ and the solution to the equation  $100\cdot x=100\cdot 1$ is still $x=1$.

Comment: I think I kind of understood your question. However, you should rephrase it because it is not easily understood. If you can include a specific example maybe someone can help you.

Comment: The two sides are equal. If you and I have the same amount of money and we both double are money then we still have the same amount of money. This is also why we can add or subtract the same value from each side and maintain the equality.

Comment: Would this not change the line graphically? or are you just "working with bigger numbers"? @MichalAdamaszek

Comment: For example, $2x + 8y = 5$ and $3x - 2y = 4$ you multiple $3x - 2y = 4$ with 4 so the $y$ falls off, but how does this not change the point of intersection, since you are raising each value of $y$ with 4? OH wait the value of x and y in the equation does not change so that means the point of intersection does not change?

Comment: Alice and Bob have the same amount of money $(A=B)$. Now let's  triple both of their money. They still have the same amount of money $(3A=3B)$. Of course, you can do this with a different constant (other than $3$) as well. As for what this does to a graph of the equation $A=B$: nothing. The plots of $A=B$ and $3A=3B$ are exactly the same - the points where $A$ and $B$ are equal.

Answer (score 1):

The line $ax+by=c$ is algebraically equivalent to $kax+kby=kc$ for some non-zero constant $k$. Geometrically, they describe the same line because all solutions in $(x,y)$ to the first are also solutions to the second.

If you're interested in the intersection of two lines $f(x)=y\space,\space g(x)=y$ then at their intersection the difference of the functions is $0$, so multiplication leaves it unchanged.

(Edit to correct mistake pointed out by FShrike)

Comment: For some *nonzero* constant $k$

Answer (score 0):

I understand what I did wrong now, $3x - 2y = 4$ multiplied by 4 is
$12x - 8y = 16$ and for the same values of x and y the equation will be correct and remain the same graphically, if you change it to the form
$y = \frac{3}2x - 2$ you will get the same values for y as in $y = \frac{12}{8}x - 2$. I had some confusion on how to interpret the function in the form $ax + by = c$. So basically to interpert $ax + by = c$ you take a value for x and y and if it equals c the coordinates (x,y) are on the graph of $ax + by = c$. Therefore multiplying the entire equation does not change its values. Please leave some feedback on my answer whether this line of thinking is correct.